# Translate custom terms in sxw report

Tags: translation, odoo

I'm using openerp 7 and working on customizing invoice report.

I've made customization to the invoice report, using `base_report_designer` and `OpenOffice`. So template I work with is an `*.sxw` file.

I wonder how to translate custom terms I added in this report.

I've tried using the OpenERP interface (`Settings -> Translations -> Application Terms -> Translated Terms`),  but it does not work.

Neither when I'm modifying the `*.po` file in `account/i18n/fr.po`.

Am i missing something in the translation process ?

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `[[ setLang(yourInvoiceObject.partner_id.lang) ]]` to your sxw file.